# Babel 7 + Typescript Unexpected token when using destructuring in function method

Tags: javascript, typescript, babeljs

I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: /Path/to/File.tsx: Unexpected token, expected ";" (73:76)
```

For:

```
interface Foo {
   bar: ({name: string, age: number}) => void;
}
```

This will not:

```
interface Bar {
   name: string;
   age: number;
}

interface Foo {
   bar: (props: Bar) => void;
}
```

`.babelrc` is

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/env",
        "@babel/typescript",
        "@babel/react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        "@babel/proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/transform-arrow-functions"
    ]
}
```

What other plugins do I need?

Comment: I see no spread. Do you mean destructuring? Where exactly is the error? How are the two code snippets related?

Comment: @FelixKling right sorry I meant `destructuring`. I posted the error I get from the terminal. I want to use the first example, not the second example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce the error in the playground (but it doesn't use Babel I guess). However, from the [Typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html#property-renaming):

> **Property renaming**
>
> You can also give different names to properties:
>
> ```
> let { a: newName1, b: newName2 } = o;
> ```
>
> Here the syntax starts to get confusing. You can read `a: newName1` as “a as newName1”. The direction is left-to-right, as if you had written:
>
> ```
> let newName1 = o.a;
> let newName2 = o.b;
> ```
>
> Confusingly, the colon here does not indicate the type. The type, if you specify it, still needs to be written after the entire destructuring:
>
> ```
> let { a, b }: { a: string, b: number } = o;
> ```

So you have to define the method as

```
interface Foo {
  bar: ({name, age}: {name: string, age: number}) => void;
}
```